# Make does not run with "sudo pecl install pdo", why?

Tags: php

[Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/631281/) is the log file, make does not run. I followed the instructions by Ronald Bauman [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=364883). Below you can find the point where it fails. How can I debug this?

```
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootq7RxQ6/PDO-1.0.3/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/PDO -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootq7RxQ6/PDO-1.0.3/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootq7RxQ6/PDO-1.0.3/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/PDO -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /tmp/pear/temp/PDO/pdo.c -o pdo.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/PDO -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootq7RxQ6/PDO-1.0.3/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootq7RxQ6/PDO-1.0.3/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/PDO -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/pear/temp/PDO/pdo.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/pdo.o
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootq7RxQ6/PDO-1.0.3/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/PDO -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootq7RxQ6/PDO-1.0.3/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootq7RxQ6/PDO-1.0.3/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/PDO -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /tmp/pear/temp/PDO/pdo_dbh.c -o pdo_dbh.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/PDO -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootq7RxQ6/PDO-1.0.3/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootq7RxQ6/PDO-1.0.3/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/PDO -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/pear/temp/PDO/pdo_dbh.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/pdo_dbh.o
/tmp/pear/temp/PDO/pdo_dbh.c: In function ‘pdo_stmt_instantiate’:
/tmp/pear/temp/PDO/pdo_dbh.c:410:8: error: ‘zval’ has no member named ‘refcount’
/tmp/pear/temp/PDO/pdo_dbh.c:411:8: error: ‘zval’ has no member named ‘is_ref’
/tmp/pear/temp/PDO/pdo_dbh.c: In function ‘pdo_stmt_construct’:
/tmp/pear/temp/PDO/pdo_dbh.c:435:6: error: ‘zend_fcall_info’ has no member named ‘object_pp’
/tmp/pear/temp/PDO/pdo_dbh.c:458:6: error: ‘zend_fcall_info_cache’ has no member named ‘object_pp’
/tmp/pear/temp/PDO/pdo_dbh.c: In function ‘zim_PDO_setAttribute’:
/tmp/pear/temp/PDO/pdo_dbh.c:752:12: error: ‘zval’ has no member named ‘refcount’
/tmp/pear/temp/PDO/pdo_dbh.c: In function ‘zim_PDO_getAttribute’:
/tmp/pear/temp/PDO/pdo_dbh.c:818:28: error: ‘zval’ has no member named ‘refcount’
/tmp/pear/temp/PDO/pdo_dbh.c: In function ‘pdo_hash_methods’:
/tmp/pear/temp/PDO/pdo_dbh.c:1122:24: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/tmp/pear/temp/PDO/pdo_dbh.c:1126:20: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
make: *** [pdo_dbh.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Answer (score 2):

`php5-mysql`, `php5-pgsql`, and `php5-sqlite` packages will provide the PDO extensions with them. Pear is not needed to achieve this.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql php5-postgres php5-sqlite
```

Answer (score 1):

While trying to install drupal7 under Debian wheezy, I encountered identical make errors as shown here.

Initial error was:
PHP Fatal error:  Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY' in /usr/share/drupal7/includes/database/mysql/database.inc on line 42

Then, installing with "pecl install pdo" gave the above make errors.

Following this:
http://drupal.org/node/784062#comment-2932820
The issue was avoided.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the PHP version used so I am just guessing the reason.  The most probable reason for compilation failure is that you are using incompatible version of PECL module and PHP version.

There was a change in Zend internals between PHP 5.4 and PHP 5.3, so the modules needed an update.

Together with the fact that PDO module is no [longer maintained](http://pecl.php.net/package/PDO) makes quite reasonable assumption that you are using way-to-old PDO module with newer PHP, which will not work for reasons I have already stated.

E.g. just use the modules (php5-mysql, php5-pgsql) provided by the distribution.